# PayPal iOS SDK authorization payment

Tags: ios, paypal

I want to do authorization payments with the PayPal iOS SDK, but it seems like PayPal is ignoring the `intent` i'am providing.

I'am setting the `intent` to `authorize`

```
[payment setIntent:PayPalPaymentIntentAuthorize];
```

but the object always return a `sale` payment.

```
Confirmation: {
  "client" : {
    "environment" : "mock",
    "product_name" : "PayPal iOS SDK",
    "paypal_sdk_version" : "2.1.0",
    "platform" : "iOS"
  },
  "response_type" : "payment",
  "response" : {
    "id" : "PAY-6RV70583SB702805EKEYSZ6Y",
    "state" : "approved",
    "create_time" : "2014-07-01T17:11:11Z",
    "intent" : "sale"
  }
}
```

Any way to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dave from PayPal here.

When you are running in the "Mock" environment, you will always get back the same response, regardless of the details of your requested payment.

If you set your environment to "Sandbox" you should get back a response that correctly reflects your payment request.

Comment: But I still have one little question, does the iOS SDK complete the authorized payment automatically? My plan is to send the authorize_id to our server and capture the payment there.

Comment: It seems like, the mobile SDK captures the payment automatically, is it intended and possible to disable?

Comment: @Leandros yes, you can have the mobile SDK `authorize` the payment, to be `captured` subsequently by your server. Take a look at our [Single Payment documentation](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md) and search for the term `authorization`.

Comment: Thanks. The error was in our backend, thanks a lot for your answer, though.